# How to click draw view background sticker?

Tags: android, view, android-canvas

[image]**I am Create sticker app and front draw view and i click sticker but sticker is back for draw view how to click my background view if is possible so please help me and main point is draw is always front view**

Comment: Add your click event logic on front view.

Comment: front view click is only draw a line but how to click my background sticker view...

Comment: Upload a screen shot

Comment: check now .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
view.bringtofront();
```

**I find this solution and is working(Solution is ) but i find some more solution it available**

Answer (score 0):

this issue with your canvas. i think you are adding sticker to different canvas which is in background.

Comment: yes i am using different canvas library to draw a shape and sticker is set in image view ...

Comment: i am putting my ans so please check it and tell some more solution if you known .